# My android bottomsheet has no background

Tags: android

I used rey5137's bottomsheet for my android app, but there is a problem that I spent days to resolve but I don't have the solution, this is my code

```
private void showcountryBottomSheet(){
mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mActivity, R.style.Material_App_BottomSheetDialog);
View v = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.showcountry_activity, null);
ViewUtil.setBackground(v, new ThemeDrawable(R.array.bg_window));
mBottomSheetDialog.heightParam(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
mBottomSheetDialog.contentView(v)
.show();
}
```

but no matter what I did, my bottomsheet has no background, even though I've set background to white in ThemeDrawable...any help?

and yes, I've asked and made it to new issue in his github but there is still no answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use set `android:background="@drawable/xyz"` to your parent layout(like LinearLayout) of `showcountry_activity`

like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    // other code
    android:background="@drawable/xyz">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: should I declare xyz_color.xml in my drawable or can I use @color/my_color to it?